# Is there the sequence $f_n : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ (that every $f_n$ is polynomial)..

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

1) Is there  the sequence $f_n : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ (that every $f_n$ is polynomial) converge uniformly on $ \Bbb{R}$ such that $f_n \to e^x$,

2)Is there  the sequence $g_n : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ (that every $g_n$ is polynomial) converge uniformly on $ \Bbb{R}$ such that $g_n \to \sin(x)$,

I think we can consider Taylor expansion for $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$, is it true?

Comment: So, can you prove the Taylor expansion converges uniformly on all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I think you need to go for a negative answer, and then proving something about one particular sequence of polynomials (such as the partial sums of the Taylor expansion) does not help.

Answer (score 0):

No.

For $e^x$, there isn't even a single polynomial with finite distance from the target (under the supremum norm, which is the right thing to consider for uniform convergence).

For $\sin x$, only constant polynomials have finite distance under the supremum norm, but a sequence of constant functions cannot converge to $\sin x$.